# Invoke lambda from another AWS account' S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Let's say I have account A with a lambda function to receive a csv file and process, and a person with account B will provide the csv files in his S3 bucket.

What is the best practice to automatically run my lambda function once he uploads new csv files in his bucket?

The way I'm trying is to use SNS and I wonder if there is a better way to just connect his bucket with my lambda funciton?

Thank you!

Comment: See: [Using Resource-Based Policies for AWS Lambda (Lambda Function Policies) - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html)